# How to prove that $x\csc x <\pi/3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

> If $x \in (0,\frac \pi6)$, then using calculus prove that $x\csc x<\frac \pi3$

**My attempt:**

let $f(x)=\csc x$$$\implies f'(x)=-\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin^2 x}$$ which is **less** than $0$ for all $x\in (0,\pi/6)$

so, $f'(x)<0$$\implies f(x)$ is **decreasing function.**

(as we know decreasing function reverses inequality)

$$\csc(0)>\csc(x)>2$$ (*notice that inequality is reversed*)and since $x$ is positive $$2x<x\csc x<\infty$$but this violates the question  and i am definitely wrong somewhere but i don't know where!

Any 
Help will be appreciated :-D

Comment: @DanielFischer yes! but i am curious what's wrong in this method.

Comment: It doesn't violate the asserted inequality, it's just weaker. Much weaker. Look whether differentiating $\frac{x}{\sin x}$ helps.

Comment: @DanielFischer what's that "weaker"?

Comment: $a < 3$ is a weaker inequality than $a < 2$. If you want to prove the latter, but your proof only proves the former, you have proved a too weak inequality. That doesn't imply that the stronger inequality doesn't hold, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer but my equality is not weaker it completely violates, question says to prove $x\csc x<\pi/3$ but what i proved is $x\csc x$ is **greater** than $2$ which is false!

Comment: No, you proved $x/\sin x > 2x$, but $2x < \pi/3$ for $x \in (0,\pi/6)$. (The "weaker" referred to the other side, $x/\sin x < \infty$ - which is much much weaker than $x/\sin x < \pi/3$.)

Comment: @DanielFischer but even if $x=.01$ my inequality tells $x\csc x >2(.01)$ which means $x\csc x$  can even go to very large number

Comment: An inequality $x/\sin x > \text{whatever}$ helps you nothing. So you need to start fresh and pursue a different road. $1/\sin x$ is decreasing on $(0,\pi/6)$, but $x$ is increasing. And the product of an increasing and a decreasing function can be increasing, decreasing, or neither. You need a different approach.

Comment: @danielfischer "These go to eleven."  Hope you know the quote.

Comment: @DanielFischer i have to think on this again(*and probably have to study inequalities again*), thanks for giving your time :-D

Comment: @deniska If $f$ (with discontinuity at $0$ removed) is decreasing on $[0,\pi/6]$, what is its maximum value there?  Is that maximum value less that $\pi/3$?

Comment: @Dr.MV i was 100% sure that my steps were wrong but i couldn't make out which step i was doing wrong

Comment: And are you OK now?

Comment: @Dr.MV i think this is my fallacy : i multiplied $x$ with $\csc x$ as such but $x$ is a variable and in that fallacy i implicitly assumed $x$ to be a constant.

Comment: Is the inequality you're trying to prove $x\csc(x)<\pi/3$?  If so, that function increases on $(0,\pi/6)$.  Then, the supremum is equal $f(\pi/6)=\pi/3$

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
f(x) = x \csc (x) = \frac{-2x\sin x}{\cos (2x) - 1},\ x \in ]0, \pi/6 [
$$
$f$ is continous everywhere on the interval, so there exists a max/min.

$$
f'(x) = \frac{-2x \sin (2x) \sin (x)}{(\cos(2x) -1 )^2} - \frac{2 \sin (x)}{\cos (2x) - 1} = -\frac{-2\sin (x)}{\cos (2x) - 1} \left( \frac{x\sin (2x)}{\cos (2x) - 1} + 1  \right) > 0  
$$
so $f$ is increasing, max at $x \to \pi/6$ calculating $f(\pi/6) = \pi/3 \Rightarrow$ inequality holds.